# No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0 was found

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7-rc-2' but:

- Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
  - Other compatible attribute:

    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7-rc-2')
- Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
  - Other compatible attributes:

    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7-rc-2')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
  - Other compatible attribute:

    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7-rc-2')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
  - Other compatible attributes:

    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7-rc-2')

Why am I getting such an error?